# Exception when Parsing Dates in Java

Tags: java

**Edited in accordance with comments**

For some reason, I seem to be getting this exception *randomly* occurring when I am trying to parse between `Date` and `String` formats in Java.

Here is a snippet of the code I’ve got (this is just for testing purposes):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
for(...){
  ...
   System.out.println("Before parsing: [" + lastEntryDate + "]");
   Date date = formatter.parse(lastEntryDate);
   System.out.println("After parsing: [" + date + "]”);
}
```

And the output:

```
Before parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:30 EST 2011]
After parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:30 EST 2011]
Before parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
After parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
Before parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
After parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
Before parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
After parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
Before parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
After parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
Before parsing: [Sun Aug 07 22:45:31 EST 2011]
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:431)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
    at java.text.DigitList.getLong(DigitList.java:177)
    at java.text.DecimalFormat.parse(DecimalFormat.java:1298)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.subParse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1936)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1312)
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:335)
    at proj01.servicebus.ServiceBus.writeFeedEntry(ServiceBus.java:211)
    at proj01.servicebus.ServiceBus.writeFeedEntries(ServiceBus.java:243)
    at proj01.servicebus.ServiceBus.access$1(ServiceBus.java:241)
    at proj01.servicebus.ServiceBus$1.call(ServiceBus.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

The problem is:

- sometimes, the parsing fails ?! (see for example, where it gives 00:00:00)
- sometimes, the exception shown is thrown ?!
- the problem seems to be random!

What is the likely cause and solution to this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to parse an empty string. Therefore the error is in the input data - unfortunately, in that case you won't *display* the bad data, as you're only calling `System.out.println` once, *after* parsing.

If you change your diagnostics to:

```
System.out.println("Before parsing: [" + lastEntryDate + "]");
Date date = formatter.parse(lastEntryDate);
System.out.println("After parsing: [" + date + "]");
```

I suspect you'll see that you get an exception when the data is missing or completely invalid; where it's parsing to "Sun Aug 07 00:00:00 EST 2011" I suspect you'll find that the input data really does have that information.

EDIT: If you're using multiple threads, you should *not* be sharing a `SimpleDateFormat` between the threads. Either create one in each thread or (my preference) use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead - it's a much better library in general, and its formatters *are* thread-safe.

Comment: ok, I edited the original post in accordance with your suggestion ... still can’t seem to see why the error occurs?!

Comment: @Larry: That sugests the problem comes before you actually get to any of the code you've shown us. What does line 211 of `writeFeedEntry` look like?

Comment: Line 211 points to the `formatter.parse()` method... but I think the problem may be what Stephen suggested, as it’s true, my code does involve multiple threads

Comment: @Larry: And you're sharing a single SimpleDateFormat? Ick - yes, that *would* be a problem. Editing.

Comment: yes, I’m declaring globally static `SimpleDateFormat formatter` then using for each thread...

Comment: @Larry: Okay, so the code snippet you gave us isn't representative of your real code :( Anyway, "don't do that" - and I've suggested a couple of alternative options.

Comment: thanks, this was the problem (PS: I did shorten the code for the questions, but seems the smallest difference is what mattered the most!)

Comment: @Larry: That's why it's often a good idea to try to create a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I down voted because your (initial) answer is simply wrong. It's a threading issue that Stephen C suggested. That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @M Platvoet: Nothing in my answer was *wrong* - it just wasn't the cause of the problem. I think there's a big difference between those two scenarios. It's not like I was giving bad advice - it's just that with the code provided, there was no reason to believe that threading would come into it. Stephen's guess was a really good one, but I don't think that means perfectly reasonable advice deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 8):

A failure that occurs "randomly" for the same input is strongly suggestive of a threading issue.  And the stacktrace tells me that you are most likely using multiple threads in this test.

I suspect the problem is that you are sharing one `SimpleDateFormat` object between multiple threads without properly synchronizing its use.  The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `SimpleDateFormat` says this:

> *"Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally."*.

Comment: that’s correct, I do have multiple threads accessing the same formatter, let me try modify to see what happens...

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to output stuff in two tiems so that we can actually always see what your trying to parse even if parsing fails:

```
System.out.print("["+lastEntryDate );
System.out.println("||"+formatter.parse(lastEntryDate)+"]”);`
```

Actually we can't see the input data that make parsing fail.

Answer (score 0):

It's worthwhile to mention that, since Java 8, a new DateTimeFormatter class has been introduced.

```
The new DateTimeFormatter class is immutable and thread-safe.
```

If we're working with Java 8 or later, using the new DateTimeFormatter class is recommended.